# Warning prints in console when using WebKit to load YouTube video

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, webview

I am using WebKit and a WKWebView to load a YouTube video into my SwiftUI application. Whenever the YouTube video plays or pauses I get this message printed in the console as a warning. I think it is due to a lack of permissions or capabilities added to my app.

Another SO thread said to add the **BackGround Modes** capability and check the **background fetch** and **background processing** boxes. I did so and I still get this message. How can I clear this warning?

> ProcessAssertion::acquireSync Failed to acquire RBS assertion 'WebProcess Suspended Assertion' for process with PID=12858, error: Error Domain=RBSServiceErrorDomain Code=1 "target is not running or doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.assertions.webkit" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=target is not running or doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.assertions.webkit}*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add this to your webview:

```
webView.allowsLinkPreview = true
```

Answer (score 4):

While [this thread](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/711426) suggests it is a warning message you could ignore, [this one](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/709919) adds:

> I had set `webView.navigationDelegate`, but not the setting mentioned above. But adding `Background fetch` and `Background Processing` capabilities stopped the messages. I didn't need to add `Remote Notifications`.

[image: https://developer.apple.com/forums/content/attachment/c866d836-e956-4f14-bc7a-6ef3762a8f3c]

Since you already did that, check if you have any version discrepancies regarding WebKit or iOS SDK (between your development environment and your execution environment, ie. where you are running your application).

And review the configuration settings of your `WKWebView` instance ([`WKWebViewConfiguration`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebviewconfiguration)).

Comment: Would you please look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77101513/resize-swift-ui-real-link-to-fit-frame

Comment: Von it was already answered, thanks anyways. Maybe you would know how to set maxWidth and maxHeight instead for intrinsicSize.

Comment: @ahmed I have seen your last comment just got answered as well!

Comment: Not quite its still a working progress, having trouble with the preview stretching to the maximum frame.