# Resize Swift UI real link to fit frame

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, hyperlink

I've created a real link in swift that displays a site with a preview. I want the preview to have a frame with maxWidth of 300 and maxHeight of 200. When I do so the preview is distorted.

I tried adding a scaled to fit and fill along with .aspect ratio modifiers, this didn't work. How can I resize the preview so it fits the frame without cutting out part of the preview?

This is how the preview is supposed to look:

[image: image1]

And this is what happens when I want to make it smaller:

[image: image2]

```
import SwiftUI

struct SwiftUIView: View {
    @State var text = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Phaq5p6SAmM"
    
    var body: some View {
        if let url = checkForFirstUrl(text: text){
            LinkPreviewView(url: url)
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                .frame(maxWidth: 300, maxHeight: 200, alignment: .leading)
                .cornerRadius(15)
        }
    }
}



import LinkPresentation
import UIKit
import SwiftUI

struct LinkPreviewView: UIViewRepresentable {
    let url: URL

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView {
        return LPLinkView()
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: Context) {
        let provider = LPMetadataProvider()
        provider.startFetchingMetadata(for: url) { metaData, error in
            guard let data = metaData, error == nil else { return }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if let linkPreview = uiView as? LPLinkView {
                    linkPreview.metadata = data
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

func checkForFirstUrl(text: String) -> URL? {
    let types: NSTextCheckingResult.CheckingType = .link

    do {
        let detector = try NSDataDetector(types: types.rawValue)
        let matches = detector.matches(in: text, options: .reportCompletion, range: NSMakeRange(0, text.count))
        if let firstMatch = matches.first {
            return firstMatch.url
        }
    } catch {
        print("")
    }

    return nil
}
```

Comment: The correct solution is found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77110270/swift-intrinsiccontentsize-uses-max-frame-to-scale-lplinkpreview/77115045#77115045

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Swift intrinsicContentSize uses max frame to scale LPLinkPreview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77110270/swift-intrinsiccontentsize-uses-max-frame-to-scale-lplinkpreview)

Comment: @HangarRash yes that is the same solution already linked. Thanks tho.

Comment: I was simply flagging your question as a duplicate of that other one. Feel free to close your question as a duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

After a lot of tests, I find that frame.size = (300, 200) and intrinsicSize = (350, 285), so the preview should get clipped.

I think the problem is the `frame` setted by LinkPreviewView is not matched by LPLinkView's `intrinsicSize`

You can have a try

```
class CustomLinkView: LPLinkView {
    init() {
        super.init(frame: .zero)
    }
    
    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        CGSize(width: frame.width, height: frame.height)
    }
}
```

Comment: @ahmed sure you can, just do what I have done, so you can keep intrinsicContentSize the same as frame. and just do size work at LinkPreviewView like `.frame(maxWidth: 300, maxHeight: 200)`. By the way, please make sure `.aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)` is added, it can keep the content looking normal when your content's aspectRatio > 1.

Comment: @ahmed as what you described, I think `contentMode: .fill` will be your choice, it 
 respect original content size and will never stretch the content, instead just clip it the most both in title and video.

Comment: The correct solution is found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77110270/swift-intrinsiccontentsize-uses-max-frame-to-scale-lplinkpreview/77115045#77115045